# What is difference between "[ x for x in temp ]" and "for x in temp"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If we assume `a` and `b` both contain 5 integers:

```
temp = [ x for x in zip(a, b) ]
```

What is the difference between these two pieces of code? Why does this work:

```
for q, p in temp:
    pass
```

But not this?

```
q = [ x for x, _ in temp ]
p = [ x for _, x in temp ]
```

The second fails with `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Both work.

Comment: This should work if `temp` really is the same in both cases. Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it works.

Let's say

```
a = range(1,6)
b = range(3,8)

temp = [ x for x in zip(a, b) ]
```

Here, x will get a tuple. It will have each element from `a` and `b` sent to `x`. So the result of this will be:

```
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7)]
```

If you want each value from the for loop to be stored in different variables, you can give:

```
temp = [(p,q) for p,q in zip(a, b)]
```

Here, p will get values `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and q will get values `3, 4, 5, 6, 7`

The result of both the list comprehensions are the same.

Now let's look at the other two.

```
q = [ x for x, _ in temp ]
p = [ x for _, x in temp ]
```

Here, the code is trying to pick values from `temp` which has `tuples`. Each iteration, two values are retrieved. For the code

```
q = [ x for x, _ in temp ]
```

it is retaining the first value into x and discarding the second value. So list `q` will have `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Similarly, for `p`, it discards the first value while retaining the second value. So list `p` will have `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

And lastly, when you look at

```
for q, p in temp:
    pass
```

You are iterating through `temp` but you are not storing the values anywhere. So once all the values in temp are iterated thru, the values of `q` and `p` will be the last element of temp which will be `(5,7)`. This will result in `q` getting `5` and `p` getting `7`.

Answer (score -1):

The first one is list comprehension and other one is simple for loop.  List comprehension is an easy way to run some loop or some conditions and it rerurns a list.

So in your example, temp will be a list.

We also have dict comprehension which returns dictionary